# Time and "fundamental" equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, loop-quantum-gravity

I have been reading articles by Carlo Rovelli.  About quantum mechanics, he says:  “The Heisenberg and Schrödinger pictures are equivalent if there is a normal time evolution in history. In the absence of a normal notion of time. The Heisenberg picture remains viable, the Schrödinger picture becomes meaningless. In quantum gravity, only the Heisenberg picture makes sense.” Also, “General Relativity does not describe evolution in time: it describes the relative evolution of many variables with respect to each other.” This concept of time supports the Loop Quantum Gravity theory. Further quoting Rovelli: “In quantum gravity, at the fundamental level, we should simply forget time.”
However, I thought that all “fundamental” theories contained time. How is this contradiction explained?

Comment: Which articles?

Comment: Quantum Spacetime: what do we know, 1999, page 12; and, The order of time, Book, pg 119, 2018)

Comment: I would like to delete this question because it basically asks, is time an emergent concept [as in LQG])? After reflecting on this, I think it is a philosophical question.

Comment: @JimJohnson In LQG, time is cosidered fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

In special and general relativity, there is not one notion of time that works for all reference frames. Time can run at a different rate as measured by different observers. As a result, we run into problems when we do not put space and time on more or less the same footing in any theory that is meant to incorporate relativity.  I can't speak about quantum gravity, but the Heisenberg picture is more friendly to quantum field theory because it allows us to think about operators as functions of both space and time. It's less neat to use a space dependent field operator and a time dependent state vector. You would have trouble writing frame-independent equations.

Answer (score -4):

There is a reason why some forces are "Fundamental." Some forces are also known as "fundamental interactions" that do not appear to be reducible to more basic interactions." Wikipedia, "fundamental interactions". The contradiction referred to in the question above as having to do with "'fundamental' theories" does not exist because theories are not subject to the time force.
This must be the defunct blog I was thrown out of some time back for my ideas that  reveal new ideas that hurt the minds of all conformists.  They're Baaaack!" Please Massa, don't throw me in the briar patch! I am welcome in the Quora website for those of you who will not leave your heads stuck in the sand.